# angular ui sortable callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-sortable

Is there a way to set a callback function with angular ui's sortable? I'd like to add ng-update="foo()" to the tbody tag below and have foo run whenever the list changes.

```
<tbody id="existingStockResults" ui-sortable ng-model="processes">
    <tr ng-repeat="process in processes" ng-class="{odd: $index%2 == 0, even: $index%2 != 0}">
        <td>{{process.process}}</td>
        <td>{{process.vendor}}</td>
        <td>{{process.desc}}</td>
            <td>{{process.cost}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="editProcess($index)">edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="removeProcess($index)">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can now specify the update function in the `ui-sortable` attribute, like this:

```
<tbody ui-sortable="{update: foo()}">
```

But there still are a few issues with the sortable directive, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Le_Sphinx/hKYWr/400/). They are currently discussed [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/460).

Comment: Things have changed. The `ui-options` attribute is no longer used, I edit my answer.

Comment: ui-sortable is now its own component that seems to have fixed some problems, but I don't know if it has the callbacks

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use an options hash with my update callback defined, in my scope like this:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    disabled: false,
    update: function(event) {
        return $scope.sortableUpdated = true;
    }
};
```

and in the template:

```
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions"> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading through the ui-sortable file (there isn't a demo of it on the angular-ui homepage, wonder why?) [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/sortable/sortable.coffee), I see that it allows for 2 callbacks -> start and update, for before and after the change you trigger.
So something like this should work:

```
<tbody id="existingStockResults" ui-sortable update="myCallback()" ng-model="processes">
```