# Angular sortable orderby object property

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a repeater ordered by a property of the objects in the repeater.

```
<div id='#TodoList' >
    <div ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:left | orderBy:'priority'">
        {{ todo.text }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The scope looks like this:

```
$scope.todos = [
    {text: 'do 1', priority: 1},
    {text: 'do 2', priority: 2},
]
```

Now I want to make the `#TodoList` sortable with jquery ui
`jQuery("#TodoList").sortable();`

How do I make the priority of each task update according to the new sortable position of the task?

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve , pls brief in simple words with e.g. if possible !!

Comment: When the user drags  task2 over task1  (changing their sorting order) I want the priority of task 2 to become 1 and the priority of task1 to become 2

Comment: Your data is managed by a JavaScript model in angular, but by the DOM in jQuery. If you mix two different kinds of data models, I wouldn't expect them to play nicely. You can make this work, but it will be hacky.

Comment: Yep. If you'd show me how to put it correctly, i'll be grateful

Comment: See if ui-sortable's callback functions can be used to update your model.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500590/angular-ui-sortable-callback/13502248#13502248

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to use it and thus came here. The only idea i had is to rescan the generated dom and based on dom changes update again the items in the model, which ain't gonna be easy.

Comment: why do u want to mix jquery with angular just make sortable directive using angular

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. Can you show me an example of using the angular-ui for that, which will update the priority of the items based on their new sorted dom position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example. A few things can be improved there... but it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/QfERt/30/

```
$("#TodoList").sortable({
   update: function( event, ui ) {
     var uiArray = $("#TodoList").sortable('toArray');
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.todos.length; i++) {
       $scope.todos[i].priority = uiArray.indexOf($scope.todos[i].text) + 1;
     }
     $scope.$apply();
   }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I hoped I wouldn't have to do, but I guess that's it. Thanks for now. I'll wait another few days for, hopefully, someone  saying something about hidden angular-ui features and then will accept your answer.

Comment: There are no hidden features that enable this but the correct use of scope.$apply in a link function of a directive containing the necessary jQuery behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/AdrianMigraso/BTDdm/

### your HTML

```
<div id='#TodoList' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:left | orderBy:'priority'">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" ></span>
            {{ todo.text }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### you AngularJS code

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [
        {text: 'do 1', priority: 1},
        {text: 'do 2', priority: 2},
        {text: 'do 5', priority: 5},
        {text: 'do 3', priority: 3},
        {text: 'do 4', priority: 4},
    ];
    $scope.$watch('todos', function(newVal,oldVal) {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });

}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me http://jsfiddle.net/S7nSt/ . The priority property ain't getting updated. Perhaps because the is absolutely no updating logic in this code.

Comment: ah, right, seems like binding from 'update' like pravelgi's answer can do it. hehe.